# Gradle build - non java project

Tags: java, build, compilation, gradle, task

My project has one .zip file in the source code that i want to put in appserver.zip file under folder 1.1.0/deployment. This .zip file again gets bundled in a .tar file.

NOTE: THIS project is not a JAVA/Groovy project i.e. there is no java programs or groovy programs

Following is my build.gradle, which is creating the correct .zip (with correct folder/ source .zip file in it) and .tar file containing the appserver.zip in it:

```
// Let say $projName, $folderArtifactoryVersion or etc variables used in the following script - are set correctly to a valid value.


task createZipFile( type: Zip) {
  // Create artifact directory
  def dirName = "build/folderDist"
  def dirDist = new File( dirName )
  dirDist.mkdirs()

  destinationDir dirDist
  archiveName "appserver.zip"

  println ''
  println 'bundleArchiveName: ' + archiveName
  into( '1.1.0/deployment' ) {
  from( "cognos/Integration/Deployment" )
    include( 'SomeCognos_deploy.zip' )
  }
}

task createTarFile( type: Zip) {
  dependsOn createZipFile
  def projName = "dircognosreporting"
  def dirParent = "build/folderArts"

  // Create artifact directory
  def dirName = "$dirParent/com/truven/folder/$projName/$folderArtifactoryVersion"
  def dirDist = new File( dirName )
  dirDist.mkdirs()

  destinationDir dirDist
  archiveName "dirCognosReporting-${folderArtifactoryVersion}.tar"

  println ''
  println 'bundleArchiveName: ' + archiveName
  println ''
  into( '' ) {
  from( "build/folderDist" )
    include( 'appserver.zip' )
  }
}

build {
  dependsOn clean
  dependsOn createTarFile
}
```

Gradle build log shows the following:

```
-bash-3.2$ /production/gradle/AKS/gradle-1.6/bin/gradle clean build
Creating properties on demand (a.k.a. dynamic properties) has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0. Please read http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtension.html for information on the replacement for dynamic properties.
Deprecated dynamic property: "folderArtifactoryVersion" on "root project 'dirCognosReporting'", value: "1.1.0.5".

bundleArchiveName: appserver.zip


bundleArchiveName: dirCognosReporting-1.1.0.5.tar

:clean
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:jar UP-TO-DATE
:assemble UP-TO-DATE
:checkstyleMain UP-TO-DATE
:findbugsMain UP-TO-DATE
:pmdIntegrationTest UP-TO-DATE
:pmdMain UP-TO-DATE
:pmdTest UP-TO-DATE
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:test UP-TO-DATE
:check UP-TO-DATE
:createZipFile
:createTarFile
:build

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 5.117 secs

-bash-3.2$
```

My 2 ?s:

1. Why the println message defined within createZipFile and createTarFile were printed at the very first stage, even before clean. If I use task build << { ... } then - as expected, i get task build already exist. If I use just build << { .... }, I get a different behaviour.
2. As build result is giving me what i need under build/folderDist and build/folderArts folders, I'm not much worried about the above bullet at this time, but WHAT should I do, so that I don't see the following lines in the output (as i dont have anything related to java in my source code). Why, gradle is just not doing only - createZipFile, createTarFile and then exit out gracefully?

*

```
:clean
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:jar UP-TO-DATE
:assemble UP-TO-DATE
:checkstyleMain UP-TO-DATE
:findbugsMain UP-TO-DATE
:pmdIntegrationTest UP-TO-DATE
:pmdMain UP-TO-DATE
:pmdTest UP-TO-DATE
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:test UP-TO-DATE
:check UP-TO-DATE
:createZipFile
:createTarFile
:build
```

*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ad 1. Because you are printing in the configuration phase, rather than the execution phase. If you want the `println` statement to be executed as part of executing the task, wrap it with `doFirst { ... }` or `doLast { ... }`.

ad 2. Someone (e.g. a parent build script) is applying the `java`, `pmd`, `checkstyle`, and `findbugs` plugins to this project. Get rid of all that. To nevertheless keep the `clean` task, apply the `base` plugin. To keep the `build` task, declare it yourself (change `build { ... }` to `task build { ... }`).

Comment: Exactly, thanks Pete. For 2nd bullet: if I comment apply plugin: 'java' line in init.d xxxxxx.gradle file, then "gradle clean build" says, no build() with an error. I basically want the output to just show - :clean, :createZipFile, :createTarFile and that's it. Any way, I can get that?

Comment: See my remark on the `build` task. Another problem I can spot is that the build script doesn't make sure that `clean` will always run before the Zip tasks when running `gradle build`. One solution is to remove the `build.dependsOn(clean)`, which is suspicious anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it's due to the reason as my /init.d folder has a somename.gradle build where I have defined **apply plugin: 'java'** within **allprojects** { ..... } section.

If I comment that out, I get an error saying build() ...not there or absent.

Comment: Please use comments or edit your question to supply updates. Note that task build your calling is configured by java plugin, without it there is no build task to call, you need to define your own task hierarchy, mimicking one used by java is good idea but not required. you can also give gradle the specific script to run using -b parameter, otherwise build.gradle is used . http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#tutorial_gradle_command_line - 11.5